# Save data using ajax in Django wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to save data from `javascript` to `django-views` using `jquery $.ajax` but the browser console will give me this error:

Here is my `javascript` content with `$.ajax`:

```
var url = $(this).attr('action');

     $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url : url,
     dataType    : 'json',
     data:{
        firstname   :   $('#firstname').val(),
        lastname    :   $('#lastname').val(),
        gender      :   $('#gender').val(),
        birthdate   :   $('#bdate').val(),
        age         :   $('#age').val(),
        address     :   $('#address').val(),
        mobile_no   :   $('#mobile').val(),
        home_no     :   $('#home').val(),
        email       :   $('#email').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken     :   $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
     },
     success:function(data){
        $('.bvc-emp-list-item-result').html(data)
     },
});
```

And here is my `views.py`:

```
def create_employee(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.POST['firstname']
        lastname = request.POST['lastname']
        gender = request.POST['gender']
        bdate = request.POST['bdate']
        age = request.POST['age']
        address = request.POST['address']
        home_no = request.POST['home_no']
        mobile_no = request.POST['mobile_no']
        email = request.POST['email']

        Employee.objects.create(
            firstname = firstname,
            lastname = lastname,
            gender = gender,
            bdate = bdate,
            age = age,
            address = address,
            mobile_no = mobile_no,
            home_no = home_no,
            email = email
        )

        # Get all employee from db.
        employees = Employee.objects.all()

        return render_to_response(
            'payroll/employee/employee-list-item.html', # template
            {'employees' : employees }, # context
            context_instance=RequestContext(request) # request
        )
```

If you want to check my `urls.py` here it is.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'payroll'
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /payroll/employee/create/
    url(r'^employee/create/$', views.create_employee, name='create_employee')
]
```

I am new to WebDev and `Django` please help.

## UPDATE

The console log generate both the `POST` error and now there is added an
`XHR finished loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/payroll/employee/create/"`.

Now the `cmd` generate this traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /payroll/employee/create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    list_ = super(MultiValueDict, self).__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'bdate'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\src\payroll\views.py", line 21, in create_employee
    bdate = request.POST['bdate']
  File "C:\Users\Web\Desktop\PyDev\projects\bvc_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'bdate'"
[20/Jul/2016 13:10:35] "POST /payroll/employee/create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18952
```

Comment: A 500 error means Django encountered an error. Check the console/error log for the cause of the error. From looking at it, I can see at least one error in your code - `Employee.object.create` should be `Employee.objects.create`.

Comment: i suspected that there is also an error in my `js` file

Comment: An error in your JS would not cause a 500 response from the server. In any case you will need to fix one thing at a time...

Comment: Post the entire error traceback, not just the final error message.  It should contain a reference to the exact line of your code that caused the error.

Comment: Also you misspelled `firtname`.

Comment: @JohnGordon oh yeah haha sad, but please wait as i am testing it

Comment: @JohnGordon i updated my question responding to your recommendation

Comment: I'll repeat: A 500 response means **something went wrong server-side**. You need to get hold of the stack trace generated by Django to find out where the error is. The problem is *not* with your JS.

Comment: @solarissmoke sir there is issue in the `bdate` i think i need to parse the string because the model `bdate` property holds `datefield()`

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer. Please leave the last stack trace with the relevant code only.

Comment: You're not POSTing a `bdate` field... hence the error. You are posting a `birthdate` field which is presumably what you need to fetch in your view code: `bdate = request.POST['birthdate']`.

Comment: @solarissmoke yea thats solve my problem about that, thanks for pointing out. Now method works perfectly now after i parse the `request.POST['birthdate']` to `date` datetype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As based to @solarissmoke suggestion i changed the `request.POST['bdate']` to `request.POST['birthdate']` since in the js file, the variable is `birthdate` not `bdate`

Then as i started to work for date parsing the Django trace give me this error:

> `ValueError: time data 'November 28, 1989' does not match format`
>   '`%Y-%m-%d'`

So i changed the code with this line according to [python date format documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
bdate =  datetime.datetime.strptime(request.POST['birthdate'], "%B %d, %Y")
```

---

Now the last problem is the `render_to_response` function because in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/) it is not recommended and is likely to be deprecated in the future i am using the lastest release `django 1.9`:

```
return render_to_response(
            'payroll/employee/employee-list-item.html', # template
            {'employees' : employees }, # context
            context_instance=RequestContext(request) # request
        )
```

I replace it with this code:

```
return render(request,
            'payroll/employee/employee-list-item.html', 
            {'employees' : employees }
        )
```

And in the js file i replace the datatype value to `html`

It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you have to pass csrf token in Ajax request call see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax.)

Otherwise it will not allow you for POST request it will request as GET and your whole data will be coming in `request.GET` instead of request.POST. So do this, try to print `request.data` and `request.post` and check where your data is , according to that use `request.data['firstname']` and `request.POST['firstname']`.